# SQL query that gives me the count of records with unique column value in table

Tags: sql, select, distinct, treasure-data

I am new to SQL and learning some basic things with Treasure Data. I have many records of reservation in a table with 11 distinct resource values that users can reserve.

This gives me the resources in a table:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT resource
FROM
  reservation
;
```

But what if I just want the output to be the number of records that get returned by the query (i.e., "11").

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) DISTINCT resource
FROM
  reservation
;
```

What is the right syntax for this? I have not been able to figure this out.

Comment: (1) Learn `group by`.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I'm removing the extraneous database tags.

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct` keyword goes **inside** the aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT resource)
FROM
  reservation
;
```